# python ignore first line with io.open

Tags: python, io, file-read

I have this piece of code:

```
with io.open('csus.csv',mode='r',encoding='latin1') as csus:
  for line in csus:
```

And I need to ignore the first (header)line. Of course I can work with a virgin boolean, check it's value during the run of the for loop, when False digest the line and set it to False otherwise. 
But I was hoping to read the first line from the file(handle?) and continue with the `for loop`

```
csus.readline()
```

does not have the expected effect, is it possible and what should I use?

As as a side question should I close the csus file? I don't think this was done in the example I copied it from and I wonder wether this `with .. as ..` statement already incorporates the close()?

Comment: Try `next(csus)`

Comment: _"`csus.readline()` does not have the expected effect"_ Are you _sure_? It works for me.

Comment: Consider looking into the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to do this for you. It's builtin to Python, so you don't have to install anything extra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
with io.open('csus.csv',mode='r',encoding='latin1') as csus:
    next(csus)
    for line in csus:
        # do something
```

The `with` statement takes care of closing the file for you.

Comment: This is the only one that doesn't run some sort of branch for each line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`enumerate` and skip the first line

```
import io
with io.open('csus.csv',mode='r') as csus:
  for i, row in enumerate(csus):
      if(i==0):
          pass
      else:
        print(str(i) + " " + row)
```

Comment: `'{} {}'.format(i, row)` is much sexier (read pythonic).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve  it with below code:

```
with open('any.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i > 0:
            print(line) # Change to line.strip() to get rid of new line after everyline
```